# titanium bluetooth permision android 6

Tags: android, bluetooth, titanium, appcelerator

Good evening, I have a problem with Android 6. How do I enable bluetooth enabled automatically?
I plugged in tiapp.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

but does not work. I always have to enter the app management and activate location services.

Answer (score 0):

Generally except your app is an power management app, you should not enable/disable the Bluetooth at your apps, but let end user to click to enable/disable it.

However if you really want to do that, just call enable() and disable() API at BluetoothAdapter.

You might as well add following permissions:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

Answer (score 0):

```
Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
[WARN] :   Binder: java.lang.SecurityException: Need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to get scan results
[WARN] :   Binder:  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
[WARN] :   Binder:  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
[WARN] :   Binder:  at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.startScan(IBluetoothGatt.java:883)
[WARN] :   Binder:  at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper.onClientRegistered(BluetoothLeScanner.java:375)
[WARN] :   Binder:  at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:56)
[WARN] :   Binder:  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

I have to enable location. as photos

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0ZWm.png)